How to derive momentum-space Feynman rules from position-space ones?
I was reading Peskin-Schroeder's QFT text (P-S) and came across Equation (4.47) stating the vertex factor when four lines meet. P-S says

the $z$-dependent factors of the diagram is: $$ \int d^4z\,e^{-iz(p_1+p_2+p_3-p_4)} = (2\pi)^4\,\delta^4(p_1+p_2+p_3-p_4)\ . \tag{4.47}$$

Here's the relevant diagram:
 .
I simply don't understand how to derive this from the given figure of a vertex? How does one obtain this expression starting from the $i\varepsilon$-prescription (aka Fourier transform) of the position-space Feynman propagator $D_F(x-y)$ in eq. (4.46)? Additionally, how's there a $z$-integral in momentum-space? Shouldn't all variables be momenta now?
